Graph Api gives this MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. on SSO
//program.cs

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddKendo();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new[] { "User.Read" })
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddScoped<GraphHelperService>();
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();


//graphHelperService.cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class GraphHelperService
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphClient;

    public GraphHelperService(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        _graphClient = graphClient;
    }

    public async Task<User> GetUserAsync()
    {
        return await _graphClient.Me.GetAsync();
       
    }
}

So when I open the incognito tab and login putting in my mail and password it works but when I open it in normal tab it gives me MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call
What I was trying to do is to get the current logged in users info so that I can display it in a navbar


MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the
AcquireTokenSilent call

I often get this exception in my side like screenshot below.

I have codes like below which worked well in my side when I didn't sign in with my account before. Just like what we can see in the codes and configurations, the controller view requires authentication to access, so the logic shall be: redirect to sign in first if unauthenticated then use the authorized GraphServiceClient to call Graph API, or we already signed in so that we could call API. But the fact is that the second time I run my application, it doesn't redirect to the sign in page but directly gives me the exception which is against my logic.
//[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

    public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        //var me = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
        return View();
    }
    
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PrivacyAsync()
    {
        var me = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
        return View();
    }
}

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    //options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

To narrow down the issue, I put the [Authorized] attribute from Controller to Privacy action method, and run my application to test again. I found that  it doesn't ask me to sign in but I can see my user account in the nav bar which shows that it already get authenticated. However, when I go to Privacy page, the exception is thrown again.
I think this is due to session. When we signed into the application, there's no cookie value in the website, after signing in, we can get a cookie named .AspNetCore.Cookies, cookie is bind to session, so that if the application is always running, if we close the browser and reopen then visit the website, the auth state is remembered, and it's recognized as the same session, so that everything worked well. If we stop and application and run again, all session status is cleared, but cookie is still stored in browser. So that browser won't redirect us to sign in. But in fact the sign in status is invalid now, then we will get this exception. This exception always trapped me during developing progress, but it won't occur in production stage as the app in production stage won't stop and run frequently.

Pls correct me if I misunderstand your concerns.

Is it possible to manage the cookies to see if the user is authenticated or not

No, this is managed by SDK so that I don't think it's a good idea to check the cookie. But I searched about this exception and I found this case which providing a good workaround for developing environment. It used a app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions to delete the cookie and redirect to the login page
